# MHL connection not working properly

Tags: nexus-4, mhl

I just bought an [MHL adapter](http://4world.pl/categories/product/391/1789/) for my Nexus 4. I have connected the adapter with a HDMI cable to the TV, plugged the microUSB into my phone and provided power on the other microUSB input as I should.

The TV showed an error message:

> Check signal cable +some small text about possible power and source problems

If I unplugged the power from the adapter, or disconnected the HDMI cable, it said:

> No Signal

So I think I was on the right source. I tried a different HDMI cable, another HDMI port on the TV, and another phone (Samsung S4), but the TV still showed the error message. It seems to me the phone did not give a signal through the microUSB port. Is there something I should turn on?

Comment: Are you sure the TV is set on the correct input?  Have you tried a different HDMI port on the TV?

Comment: I have tried HDMI 1 and 4, same result.

Comment: That leaves either the device or the TV as culprit. Can you try on a different TV? Or a different device with the same TV?

Comment: Apparently the Nexus 4 does not work with MHL, it has SlimPort instead. Can someone confirm this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [András' comment](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/59421/mhl-connection-not-working-properly#comment-80734) says, the Nexus 4 uses Slimport not MHL. I use [this Slimport adaptor](http://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/B009UZBLSG/ref=pe_217191_31005151_dp_1) to connect my N4 to a TV.